# Only one class of my class library is available in a Visual studios 2010 solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, class, dll

I have made a C# class library using Visual Studios 2010. There are 4 classes in the library: Day, Location, Settings, Weather.

In my separate solution I have added a reference to this class library by right clicking "References" > Browse > and selecting the class library in the class libraries bin folder.

For some reason only the `Location` class is available for use in the other other solution.

If I attempt to instantiate the `Day` class for example, I get the following error:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'Day' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'WeatherApplicationClassLibrary' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)  E:\uni\System
>   Development\Weather-Application\WeatherApplication\MainWindow.xaml.cs 33  44  WeatherApplication

Why is this?

Comment: Please, show the definition of your classes.

Comment: Are you sure all the projects are targetting the same Framework version?

Comment: @king.code How would I do that?

Comment: @crm You need to show the code.

Comment: @GaneshR. The Location class is no different from the other yet only that class is available in the other solution?

Comment: Are all your classes Public? And in the same namespace as WeatherApplicationClassLibrary

Comment: @crm We need to see how you defined your classes because there's probably some issue with the definition. Otherwise nobody can help you here.

Comment: @GaneshR. That was the problem. Please feel free to answer.

Comment: @crm As king.code mentioned earlier, it is easier to help out if one puts up same code. I would have considered putting up part of the class definition as part of the question for faster issue resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all your classes public and in the same namespace as WeatherApplicationClassLibrary? If not correct it.